# Need Step Information in report.json for Protractor-cucumber tests

Tags: cucumber, protractor, chai, cucumberjs

I'm using "protractor-cucumber-framework" to use Cucumber along with Protractor for automation(Using CHAI as Assertion Library).

I'm using resultJsonOutputFile: './report.json' to generate a JSON log report. I can not see step information in the log file rather it just shows passed attribute for each block. Sample feature file and and JSON report generated attached below.

[sample json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhXJ0.png)

[sample feature file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybKWi.png)

I want to include the text after "Then" in the feature file for ex. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `resultJsonOutputFile` will generate json file attributed to protractor and will contain basic specs information. Since you are using Cucumber as your testing framework with protractor you would have to generate `Cucumber-Report.json` which cucumber generates.It will have all your step definition details! In order to achieve this you could add below code in your `hooks.js` file:

```
var Cucumber = require('cucumber'); //npm install -g cucumber
var jsonReporter = function () {
"use strict";
var outputDir = './Reports/';
var JsonFormatter = Cucumber.Listener.JsonFormatter();
JsonFormatter.log = function (string) {
    if (!fs.existsSync(outputDir)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(outputDir);
    }

var targetJson = outputDir + 'cucumber_report.json';
    fs.writeFile(targetJson, string, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Failed to save cucumber test results to json file.');
            console.log(err);
        } 
    });
};
this.registerListener(JsonFormatter);

module.exports = jsonReporter;
```

This would create a `Reports` folder and in that you would see `cucumber_report.json` file

Comment: Thanks @igniteram1 for the answer. As I'm new to cucumber I'm not able to wired up this hooks.js to my stepdef file. I've feature file, hooks.js,stepdefinition file in a folder. Sibiling to this folder I've conf.js. Can you please tell me where should I require this hooks file which will create json file.

Comment: you have to require them in your `conf.js` in `cucumberOpts` along with your step definitions!

Comment: Yeah I did, and I'm able to generate json file as expected. Thank you

Comment: Glad It worked! Please accept the answer if it solved your issue as it would help others having similar problem :)

Comment: @igniteram, Can we have this hooks.js code in conf.js either in anyof the block like onPrepare/Oncomplete etc. instead of having in separate file and requiring in require block?